# Op amp based phase inverter. Two examples. Which is best?

Tags: operational-amplifier, phase-shift

I'm a beginner in electronics. I've got a fun guitar pedal adventure going. Now I'm in need of phase shifting.
I'm making a parallel effect mixer, and as some pedals are inverting the signal, I'd like to flip it on the fx return.

**Example A**  is one I found.

**Example B** is my own way of thinking it before researching.

- Will B work as well?
- Will they sound the same?
- Which would you use if any?
- How can either be improved?

[image]

Comment: If you are trying to create a guitar "Phasor" then neither of those circuits will do the job at all.

Comment: No, I'm making a parallel effect mixer, and some pedals are inverting the signal, so I'd like to flip it on the fx return. Otherwise the parallel signals may cancel eachother out.

Comment: Well. I just found this which answers my questions pretty well
https://sound-au.com/project107.htm

Comment: Why not make an answer of your discovery but, be prepared to justify why it will sound better/worse than the other two (something an EE would be loath to embark on I suspect). Then maybe make a note or two about improvements (again, something that an EE would probably not commit to without firm specification/requirements changes). In other words, you didn't get any answers from an EE because some parts of your question are not directly EE related. I thought you might wish to know this for the future.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my questions from this article by Eliot Sound:
https://sound-au.com/project107.htm

**Will B work as well?**
Apparently this is the conventional way to do a phase inverter.
Primary drawback is the inverted signal goes through an extra opamp.
The benefits of using example A is that the opamp remains in circuit all the time, the output impedance is constant and the switching is simplified, using a single pole switch.

**Will they sound the same?**
"the likelihood of hearing the difference is minimal"

**Which would you use if any?**
The article tries to tell that there is a way to keeping the circuitry as straightforward as possible. There's one drawback of the new method (here example A) which is that any appreciable capacitance will cause the circuit to act as a phase shift network at high frequencies, which although generally inaudible is considered by some to be unacceptable.
My own conclusion - I'll giv the conversional circuit a shot at first.

**How can either be improved?**
I guess there's a better reason to answer this if I run into issues...